# group selection & checkbox in ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

In my Angular application I have a grid that is almost identical to the Group Selection example in the ag-Grid docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#gsc.tab=0

My requirement is slightly different in that my expand button needs to both expand the row and select the row.  As you see in the plunker example selection and expansion are two separate click events, but I am looking to select the row and expand that same row in one click, without having the user click on the checkbox and the expand button.  I have tried doing this with css by making the checkbox transparent and placing it over the expand icon, but the click is highjacked so only one event will fire...

Is this possible in ag-Grid?

In my component by columnDefs for the column that has my checkbox and expand icon looks like so:

```
...
       this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [

            {
                headerName: '', width: 100, cellRenderer: 'group',
                // for parent row selection - checkboxes for parent rows
                checkboxSelection: function(params) {
                    return params.node.canFlower;
                },
                cellRendererParams: { value: ' ' }, colId: 'PlusIcon', pinned: 'left', cellClass: 'center'

            },
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to the `rowGroupOpened` [event](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#gsc.tab=0) and set the row to [selected](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#gsc.tab=0):

```
// inside the ag-grid tag
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"

// inside the AppComponent class
  onGroupOpened(event){
    event.node.setSelected(true)
    console.log(event)

  }
```

[plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nh9HenE15jKDuK23KCVV?p=preview)

Comment: Ingenious!  But what made you think to listen for rowGroupOpened event?  Is this what fires when the checkbox is clicked?  I am assuming this is how you are 'connecting' the event of opening a row and selecting a row?

Comment: Yep, you can check out all the events that are available to you here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Ok got that part, BUT I still don't quite understand why do we have to add $event as an argument to `(gridReady)="onGridReady()"` and not just `onGroupOpened()` ... I noticed it does not work without that.  If we have a reference to the rowNode from `onGridReady($event)` than why do we need it in `gridReady()`

Comment: the `$event` is a different parameter that gets passed to each function. I took this plnkr example from the ag-grid website and quite literally just added what I have in this answer. So I can't quite vouch for everything in the example